# Gorm main window does not accept drag-and-drop

Tags: grails-orm, gnustep

When I try to add any widget (label, button ...) to main application Window in Gorm, the Window does not accept the widget. I try to drag and drop but nothing wants to 'stick'. When I select and left click on button widget in palette window the curson changes to '2 green squares'. When I start dragging it changes to '2 black squares'.

Another problem is that the 'Document' window opens really long window (stretches about 5 times the width of my screen) but apart from NSOwner, NSFirst, My Window and NSMenu icons it is empty.

Any ideas what is wrong?

I'm running linux with fluxbox-1.1.1
I've compiled gorm-1.2.8 and gnustep-startup-0.22.0 that contains:

ffcall-1.10
gnustep-back-0.16.0
gnustep-base-1.18.0
gnustep-gui-0.16.0
gnustep-make-2.0.7
gnustep-objc-1.6.0
libffi-3.0.1

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a compatibility issue or some conflict between existing run time libraries and the new ones that I'm trying to add. Doesn't seems like there's a straightforward answer for this. Nevermind, I gave up trying atm. Maybe later when I setup another Linux box I give it a try - I'll stay with Mac OS X for now :)